# PHP include not executing code

Tags: php, include

I have an include in the head of my php file:

```
include 'scripts/tracking_code.php';
```

In there, I run a basic test with if/else and echo some basic text.

Problem is that nothing is getting printed to screen.

I then just tried to print something a little more basic... The tracking_code.php now simply includes this:

```
echo "<!-- This is the file -->";
```

Still nothing?

I know the include is getting included because when I turn E_ALL error reporting, the $_GET[] call throws a "Notice: Undefined index:"

Here is my original code (before simply replacing with "echo" (as above))

```
<?php

$trackingid = $_GET['trackingid'];

if ( !empty( $trackingid ) ) {
    echo "<!-- trackingid: $trackingid -->";
} else { 
    echo "<!-- trackingid is empty -->";
}
?>
```

Yet nothing is ever printed?

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the source and not the HTML output (which would render HTML _comments_ invisible)?

Comment: Definitely looking at the source ... I am printing before any HTML and there is nothing appearing

Comment: `<!-- trackingid: $trackingid -->` signifies a _comment_ in HTML and you'll not see it on the screen.

Comment: Yes: Right click -> View Source - It is a comment because I don't want it printing on screen for consumers to see

Comment: It would appear that comments do not print in the source before the <DOCTYPE> tag... Would this be correct?

Comment: `<?php
echo "<!--No!! comments will not be 'unavailable' if they appear before the 
!doctype declaration -->";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 3):

Is your tracking script `echo "<!-- This is the file -->";` or is it

```
<?php
  echo "<!-- This is the file -->";
?>
```

Because without the php tags, there's a good chance that your `require` call actually makes PHP go "this is not actually a PHP file and as such I cannot require it" but with the error/warning repressed due to whatever error reporting settings are active when you run the code.